# Calculating Walsh Hadamard Transform

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, boolean-algebra, cryptography, boolean-ring

Can anyone say me the steps involved in  calculating Walsh Hadamard Transform $(W_f(a))$ for a Boolean function $f(x)=x^3$ in a finite field $GF=F_4$?